# Pip install -r requirements.txt on Git Pull?

Tags: python, git, pip

I've got package management for Python going through pip right now, but I keep having people on my team forget to redo pip install -r requirements.txt when rerunning our code base and then getting confused about why stuff doesn't work. That said, is there any way I can tie that command into something else that they always have to do anyway, like `git pull` so that it's done for them and they don't need to think about it?

Comment: I would look into [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/index.html)

Comment: A scripted solution may work for yourself, and possibly people who can be made aware that they should use the script solution if/when they don't want to think about what their doing; But teaching/arising people to think about what their doing is not something a scripted solution can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a shell script in the git [post-merge hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), which will execute whenever a merge takes place.  Just be aware that this hook will execute on every merge (all pulls that actually do something are a merge, but not all merges are pulls).

I don't know if its possible to automatically install a client side hook when a repository is cloned, but you should at least be able to get your post-merge hook installed once instead of getting your team to remember to do something with every pull.

Comment: If you want to distribute a repo with such a hook embedded, you could, scrub your .git/config and other git meta data to make sure your not distributing other limitations; and then package the whole git repo, or just the `.git` portion that matters as a tar/zip, and make people copy-extract-and-work from that. Though I still want to push for educating your users first, reserving something this drastic for desperate scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

A `post-merge` hook should work fine here. Open the file `.git/hooks/post-merge` in your project's `.git` directory. Paste the following code snippet in the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD)"

check_and_run() {
       echo "$changed_files" | grep --quiet "$1" && eval "$2"
}
        
check_and_run requirements.txt  "/path/to/virtualenv/bin/pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt"
```

Run `chmod +x post-merge` to make the file executable.

Thats it. Now every time when you do git merge and there is a change in `requirements.txt` file `pip install` will run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the power to add a tool to the path of all your users; eg you all work on a single server. Creating a script to do that would be trivial.

Essentially it would be

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Save as `git-pull2`
# Mark as executable (chmod +x git-pull2)
# Include on system path.

git pull $@
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The `@$` will pass all command arguments to the scripted `git pull`, though I won't guarantee that will work 100% of all the time, but it should cover most use cases.

You can name it whatever you like, I've not tested replacing git internal commands with scripted ones, eg I don't advise naming it `git-pull` as that may conflict with the real git-pull and enter a cyclic loop, but git may also be smart enough not to recurse like that.

When git expands custom commands the first hyphen after the `git` keyword is dropped, eg to run `git-pull2` you could run it literally as `git-pull2` or as an embedded git command as `git pull2`.